# Does using an image transform significantly slow down training?

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I see image transforms used quite often by many deep learning researchers. They seem to be treated as if they are free GPU or CPU cycles.

Example:

```
transformations = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(255),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ])

train_set = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + "/train", transform = transformations)
```

In this specific case would it not be infinitely better to process the images upfront and save them out for future use in some other format? I see this sometimes but extremely rarely.

Or am I wrong, and transformers on a GPU are just so fast it's not worth the extra code or hassle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on how you set up the dataloader. Generally, the transforms are performed on the CPU, and then the transformed data is moved to the GPU. Pytorch dataloaders have a 'prefetch_factor' argument that allows them to pre-compute your data (with transforms) in parallel with the GPU computing the model. That being said, with fixed transforms like you have here, pre-computing the entire dataset and saving it prior to computing could also be a valid strategy.

Comment: Awesome! Coming form Keras there is still a lot to learn. The Key was definitely in the data loader as you pointed out. I had some serious flaws in my dataloader. `train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)` vs `train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=64, shuffle=True, num_workers = 8, prefetch_factor = 8, pin_memory=True, persistent_workers=True)`